# Giving priority to test cases in Selenium/Serenity/JUnit

Tags: java, selenium, junit, serenity-bdd

I have few test suite's/stories in my testing framework.

I would like to set priority to test suites and also test cases inside them.

For example test that deletes all the profiles inside the application, should be executed before the test that inserts profiles. Also test suite that inserts all the profiles to application should be executed before suite that does some operations on them etc.

How do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set priority in this way

```
        @Test(priority = 1,alwaysRun = true)
        public void rentalhomesHomePage() throws InterruptedException {
            //Your test case

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
 @Test(priority = 2)
        public void testcase1() throws Exception {
            //code

        }

 @Test(priority = 4)
        public void testcase2() throws Exception {
            //code

        }

 @Test(priority = 3)
        public void testcase3() throws Exception {
            //code

        }
@Test(priority = 1)
        public void testcase4() throws Exception {
            //code

        }
```